# После изменения имени программы диспетчер задач выводит старое

Tags: windows

Возникла необходимость поменять имя исполняемого файла одной проги. Сделал стандартно - просто переименовал. Теперь самое интересное: tasklist выводит имя процесса новое, а диспетчер задач старое. Компьютер был перезагружен для чистоты эксперимента. Как это возможно и что делать?

Comment: Диспетчер в Windows 10?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Диспетчер задач вывод описание файла (2), а tasklist - название файла (1). Чтобы изменить описание, можно воспользоваться программами наподобие ResEdit.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]